# Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm running into trouble with my RemoveTail function which executes the code: destroy(gameObject).  This snake game creates a clone of the my Snake prefab and I control the Snake's length by assigning a "tail" and deleting the "tail" gameobject if maxSize is reached.  I understand that my error is due to the game deleting my tail which is a clone of the prefab instead of deleting an instance of Snake.  Any ideas or suggestions on how I may resole this issue?

Snake script

```
public class Snake : MonoBehaviour {

private Snake next;  
public Snake GetNext() {
    return next;
}

public void SetNext(Snake IN) {
    next = IN;
}

public void RemoveTail() {      // This method destroys the gameObject assigned as tail
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

public static Action<string> hit;

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if (hit != null)
        hit(other.tag);
    if (other.tag == "Food")
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Excerpt from my GameController script

```
void TailFunction() {
    Snake tempSnake = tail; // Create a temp Snake variable to store tail information
    tail = tail.GetNext();  // Now that we have a copy of original tail in tempSnake, we set the next Snake gameobject as our new tail
    tempSnake.RemoveTail(); // Remove the original tail gameObject
}

void Movement() {
    GameObject temp;
    nextPos = head.transform.position;
    switch (direction) {
        case Direction.North:
            nextPos = new Vector2(nextPos.x, nextPos.y+1);
            break;
        case Direction.East:
            nextPos = new Vector2(nextPos.x+1, nextPos.y);
            break;
        case Direction.South:
            nextPos = new Vector2(nextPos.x, nextPos.y-1);
            break;
        case Direction.West:
            nextPos = new Vector2(nextPos.x-1, nextPos.y);
            break;
    }
    temp = (GameObject)Instantiate(snakePrefab, nextPos, transform.rotation);
    head.SetNext(temp.GetComponent<Snake>());
    head = temp.GetComponent<Snake>();
    return;
}

void TimerInvoke() {
    Movement();
    if (currentSize == maxSize)
        TailFunction();
    else
        currentSize++;
}
```

Comment: are you initializing the tail variable? If yes, can you please share relevant code.

Comment: The destroy line is meant to destroy the tail but you are destroying the actual object. Is your wording confusing or you are doing it wrong? I think your destroy line should be Destroy(next.gameObject);

Comment: I'm not initializing the tail variable.  My snake consists of cubes.  I instantiate one cube and assign it as the head and I keep creating new cubes in the direction my snake is traveling in.   I then store the last cube in my snake as the tail and I destroy the "tail" if my max size is reached.  I'm constantly creating a new cube "head" and destroying my last cube "tail" as my snake moves through the grid.

Comment: Well, you **have** to initialize `tail` somewhere or it will always be `null`.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion.  In my head if was thinking instantiate instead of initializing - I did not instantiate a cube as the tail but rather I instantiated a cube, set it as a head and as a tail.  I believe I'm initializing the tail with my TailFunction().  Is that not the case?

Comment: I see where I messed up now.  I dragged my prefab into the script's inspector and deleted my original snake cube.  Instead of assigning my original snake cube as tail when the game began and then deleting the gameobject, my program assigned my prefab directly as the tail and then attempted to delete the prefab outright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I dragged my prefab into my inspector and deleted my original snake cube.  Instead of assigning my original snake cube as tail when the game began and then deleting the gameobject, my program was assigning my actual prefab as the tail and attempting to delete the prefab outright.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to solve this issue by passing the prefab into variable and I faced the same issue. Then I've seen that the instantiated gameobject gets destroyed or enabled false before the "Destroy (exampleGameobject)" command.
Then I tried the command like this:
If(exampleGameObject.activeInHierarchy)
Destroy (exampleGameObject)

Then I didn't received any kind of LogError like this.