# Unity giving error for removing a component using "Destroy"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Earlier today, I was trying to remove a component to prevent conflicts when setting a Rigidbody2D's velocity, as I needed to set the object's velocity when I normally had a script on the object that set its velocity to something that I didn't want. Therefore, I had to remove the component (it was completely useless anyway in the circumstance that I was in). I knew that the Destroy function worked for removing components, so I used this code to remove the component I wanted to:

```
RandomHorizSpeed component = thing.GetComponent<RandomHorizSpeed>();
Destroy(component);
```

However, when running this code, I got an error and the component was not removed (I can't post images yet, so here's a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKIUU.jpg))

I've looked it up on the internet and I'm doing exactly what the forums/documentation are telling me to do, and I'm also not exactly sure what this error actually means. If someone could show me how to properly remove a component during runtime, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to destroy a component on a prefab

Comment: Is there any way to properly do this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973360/destroying-assets-is-not-permitted-to-avoid-data-loss) help?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I realized that I was referencing the prefab itself, not the instantiated object. Thanks!